# jQuery loading content from external html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, thickbox

I want to display some html files content with the WordPress thickbox. I am using following code. This works fine, but the problem is that, with this method I cannot utilize the WordPress core functionality, as it can display only the html file content.

```
jQuery('#test').load(url + '/files/' + name + '.html',
    function() {                
        tb_show('', '#TB_inline?inlineId=test&width=640&TB_iframe=true');       
    }
);
```

The HTML file content is simple, it contains only form elements.

Is there any way that instead of loading the file from the external html file, I can store it somewhere inside the file and display it?

Comment: url is in the same domain where this code is present right?

Comment: OR in your function.php create an ajax function add_action and paste your html form in it. Call that ajax function using $.ajax or $.post url will be wp-admin/admin-ajax.php. Put the response of ajax into $(element).html(response) on tb_show callback function. If you dont understand this follow the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is the problem, but of course you can do that:

Embed the HTML code wherever you want in your html code:

```
<div id="external-code" style="display:none;">
  <!-- Form and inputs here -->
</div>
```

Then, you can use the [`html()` jquery function](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to embed the hidden content:

```
jQuery('#test').html($('#external-code').html());
```

#### Better way:

In the previous way, you are doing an extra step, you can do something like this with ThickBox if the content is on the same page:

```
<div id="my-content-id" style="display:none;">
     <p>
        This is hidden! It will appear in ThickBox when link is clicked.
     </p>
</div>
```

To show this via href:

```
<a href="#TB_inline?width=640&inlineId=my-content-id" class="thickbox">Open ThickBox!</a>
```

Show it using `TB_Show` function:

```
tb_show('', '#TB_inline?inlineId=my-content-id&width=640&TB_iframe=true');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.get('test.html')
.success(function(data) {
 $('div.content').html(data);
});
```

Replace test.html with your url.

Answer (score -1):

You can try storing it like this in your page

```
<script type="text/template" id="tpl-list">
<input type="textbox" id="txtbox1" />
</script>
```

Then to display it, do something like

```
$("body").html($("tpl-list").html());
```